# do you need to know Haskell to code in marlowe

Tags: haskell, marlowe

I'm interested to play with Marlowe in a textual way.
when I read [this tutorial](https://prod.meadow.marlowe.iohkdev.io/tutorial/#embedded-marlowe) or read some code examples [here](https://github.com/logicalmechanism/Marlowe-Plutus-Contracts), it seems to me that I have to be knowledgeable about Haskell's basics, mainly variables and functions, to be able to write Marlowe code.

is my assumption right?

ps: I'm not interested by blocky or js

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to know some Haskell basics to edit your Marlowe contracts if you don't want to use Blockly or JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use blocky or js (Marlowe is built assuming you will), then your best bet is to try to learn Plutus and write your contracts using that. The [plutus Pioneer Program](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK8ah7DzglhhJzuiz7X33UCHSTYPB-8Jt) is a great place to get guided help learning how to write smart contracts using Plutus. Plutus makes Haskell a tad bit more accessible. And you can learn Haskell with Cardano and smart contracts in mind.

If you reallllly don't want anything to do with Haskell, then just hang tight, [IELE](https://developers.cardano.org/en/virtual-machines/iele/about/the-iele-virtual-machine/) will let you use your very own favorite programming language (Java, C#, Rust, javascript, any really many more) to write smart contracts.

Comment: Great answer in that it looks past the specific wording of the question and identifies the reason behind it.